# Complex states with Angularjs and ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, calendar, angular-ui-router

I'm building a week view calendar with Angular and UI-router, and have run into a couple of problems regarding states, and scopes.

My first problem is with navigating to a different week. With my url `/schedule/2015/W31`, I've only been able to change the year and week (without reloading the controller) by using `$location.path(...)`, and updating the calendar on `$locationChangeSuccess`. This is obviously not ideal. Is there a better option? ... preferably without using query strings.

Further to that, I have my default state `schedule` which displays my calendar, and action buttons at the top:

[image: Calendar]

When I click the `+ Add` button, I move to a state `schedule.add` which switches out the actions for buttons such as `Cancel` and `Done`.

My issue is that because I'm trying to persist the calendar across the states, using child states and `reloadOnSearch: false`, any `ng-click` on the buttons refers to the `schedule` scope. Here's the config for these states.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('schedule', {
        url: '/schedule/:year/{week:W[0-9]{2}}',
        controller: 'ScheduleController',
        templateUrl: 'sections/week/week.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false
    })
    .state('schedule.add', {
        url: '/add',
        views: {
            view: {
                template: '',
                controller: 'ScheduleAddController'
            }
        },
        reloadOnSearch: false
    });
```

I was hoping that this way of building the calendar would enable me to use a different state and controller for each piece of functionality of the calendar (i.e. rescheduling, and tons of other functions it has to do.)

Thanks for any input!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ui-router's $state.href on anchors and avoid manually updating the location.

You can get the $state var in templates and other child scopes if you attach it to the `$rootScope` in main module's run method.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.run(function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
 });
```

This is pretty handy and is recommended by ui-router team. Now you can access `$state` in your templates and controllers.

```
<a {{ $state.href('schedule', {year: '2015', week: 31}) }}></a>
```

and in `ScheduleController` you can listen to the `$stateChangeSuccess` event.

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
    // re initialise scope vars
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The issue here is ui-router doesn't update if you're trying to navigate to the same state, even with different params. This is why I've taken to using `$location`, and `$locationChangeSuccess`

Comment: @Leon No, it has been working for [quite a long time](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/289). But the code in the answer is sloppy and needs fixing.

Comment: @estus how the code is sloppy? it's just a snippet not the working code of course.

Comment: `$state` service isn't available on the scope, and there's no href attribute.

Comment: you are probably new to the Angular, see the updated answer.